# How can I import xml.dom.mindom

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to import xml.dom.minidom in order to read and edit an xml file but am getting an error.

import xml.dom.minidom

I get the error message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xml.dom'; 'xml' is not a package

Comment: How do you know it has been installed?

Comment: Can you provide the code you used to produce this error?

Comment: The code I used was import xml.dom.minidom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be due to a file name issue (such as xml.py). There may be a conflict with the file name when compiling. Rename it to solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem.